# how can I record data from different rows on a single line in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I wonder, how can I record data from different rows on a single line.

If customer has more than one shop in one row, then  I want to bring up its appropriate tariff,name and cug, for example id = 1.

If the shop1 = 577 is fixed on the customer, then its corresponding value should be written in the CUG field, for example id = 2.

There is a table:

```
create table transaction (id, shop1, sho2,shop3,shop_name,tariff,cug) as
 select   1, 789, null, 987, bundle2, 5, 0  from dual union all
 select   1, 789, null, null , bundle1, 4, 0 from dual union all
 select   1, null,null,987, bundle2, 6, 0 from dual union all
 select   2, null,null,987, bundle2, 6, 0 from dual union all
 select   2, null, 635,null, bundle1, 8, 0 from dual union all
 select   2, 577, null, null, 0, 3, cug2 from dual union all
 select   2, null, 635, 987, bundle2, 5, 0 from dual union all
 select   3, null, 852, null, bundle1, 6, 0 dual union all
 select   4, 753, 357, null, bundle2, 1.5, 0 from dual union all
  select   5, 369, 147, 422, bundle1, 4.5, 0 from dual ;
```

My expected table:

| id | shop1 | shop2 | shop3 | shop_name | tariff | cug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 789 | null | 987 | bundle2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | null | 635 | 987 | bundle2 | 5 | cug2 |
| 3 | null | 852 | null | bundle1 | 6 | 0 |
| 4 | 753 | 357 | null | bundle2 | 1.5 | 0 |
| 5 | 369 | 147 | 422 | bundle1 | 4.5 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?
Your description is difficult to follow.

> ```
> create table transaction (id, shop1, shop2,shop3,shop_name,tariff,cug) as
>  select   1, 789, null, 987, 'bundle2', 5, '0'  from dual union all
>  select   1, 789, null, null , 'bundle1', 4, '0' from dual union all
>  select   1, null,null,987, 'bundle2', 6, '0' from dual union all
>  select   2, null,null,987, 'bundle2', 6, '0' from dual union all
>  select   2, null, 635,null, 'bundle1', 8, '0' from dual union all
>  select   2, 577, null, null, '0', 3, 'cug2' from dual union all
>  select   2, null, 635, 987, 'bundle2', 5, '0' from dual union all
>  select   3, null, 852, null, 'bundle1', 6, '0' from dual union all
>  select   4, 753, 357, null, 'bundle2', 1.5, '0' from dual  union all
>  select   5, 369, 147, 422, 'bundle1', 4.5, '0' from dual ;
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   id,
>   max(shop1) shop1,
>   max(shop2) shop2,
>   max(shop3) shop3,
>   /*max(shop_name)*/ shop_name,
>   max(tariff) tarif,
>   max(cug) cug
> from transaction t
> join (select id midd,
>       max(shop_name) msn
>       from transaction
>       group by id) m
> on id = midd
> and shop_name = msn
> group by id,shop_name;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | SHOP1 | SHOP2 | SHOP3 | SHOP_NAME | TARIF | CUG
> -: | ----: | ----: | ----: | :-------- | ----: | :--
>  1 |   789 |  null |   987 | bundle2   |     6 | 0  
>  2 |  null |   635 |   987 | bundle2   |     6 | 0  
>  3 |  null |   852 |  null | bundle1   |     6 | 0  
>  4 |   753 |   357 |  null | bundle2   |   1.5 | 0  
>  5 |   369 |   147 |   422 | bundle1   |   4.5 | 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1429a2ae5399d3b6c097a49af0f853c1)*